# MongoDB Algorithm for an Object Collecting Game

Tags: mongodb, algorithm, sorting, nosql

I am making a game.  Part of the game is to collect objects.  You get points for "diversity" so each object in category has properties.  If you have collected an object with a certain property, the multiplier for that property is no longer applied to any of the other objects with the property.  The points are calculated by combinig all the unqiue values for each property you have collected, and then multiplying by the coefficient for that property. For example:

```
Points
Category: Toys
Base: 2
Shape: 7
Material: 10
Color: 5

Bouncy ball:             Snow Globe:
category: sphere         category: sphere    
shape: round             shape: round
material: rubber         material: glass
color: swirls            color: clear

Collected:
bases = my_objects.length * base = 2 * 2 = 4
shapes = array('round').length * 7
materials = array('rubber', 'glass') * 10
color = array('swirls', 'red') * 5

score = bases + shapes + materials + color = 4 + 7 + 20 + 10 = 41
```

The objects are stored as nosql documents (mongodb).  My question is, what is the best way to select all the remaining objects from the database in the order of which uncollected objects will add the most points to the user's score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further exploring the problem, it seems my goal is irrelevant.  As soon as something else is collected, the whole order of which object yields the most points will drastically change, so there is no point in ordering in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

store the score total in the document and then you can sort by that descending (using an index if desired)

you can't "sort by a+b+c" in mongo yet so that is likely best

Comment: the score for each document depends on who is logged in and what they have collected previously.  Storing it in the document would require me to recalculate the score for millions of objects every time a user collected a new object